# Left invariant vector field question

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, vector-fields

This question is an exercise from Jeff Lee's *Manifolds and Differential Geometry*

Let $\tilde{X}$ be the left invariant vector field corresponding to $X\in L(V,V)$ (That is, $\tilde{X}_g=(dL_g)_e X$). Furthermore, let $f$ be a linear functional on $L(V,V)$ and define the linear functional $f_{,X}$ by $f_{,X}(A)=f(A\circ X)$.

We are required to show $\tilde{X}f=f_{,X}$. He then says the hint/solution is

$(\tilde{X}f)(A)=df|_A(\tilde{X}_A)=f(A\circ X)$.

I think I am okay with the first equals sign in the above line but I have no idea how he shows the middle equals the right hand side of the above equations.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is $L(V,V)$ ?